# How to implement an object cache using ORMLite

Tags: java, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite and wanted to know if there is a way to implement a cache in order to prevent querying multiple times for the same object. 
For example when it is annotated as "foreign = true" and "foreignAutoRefresh = true"

The question is not about "how to make a cache" but "how can I make ORMLite look for an object in, say, a WeakHashMap and query for it in the DB if it is not found there"

Comment: do you mind marking my post as answer?

Answer (score 3):

I have been using ORMLite for Android for a while now, and I would advise you against such a cache, if not natively built-in. Even Hibernate's cache does play some tricks on you sometimes, and they literally put years of effort into it.
I would rather build a mini-cache in a DAO or something (e.g., as described [here](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/6.htm)), which gives you more control anyway (works pretty well for me). BTW, ORMLite's main contributor even considered to [remove "foreignAutoRefresh"](https://groups.google.com/group/ormlite-user/browse_thread/thread/554b477f173b8e1a) because of update-issues.

Comment: I am using foreignAutoRefresh and I am facing an interesting case http://stackoverflow.com/q/22709958/459904 foreignAutoRefresh may save another object into database for foreign field ?

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI but we have added an object cache to [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) native in version 4.26.  It supports a `WeakReference` and `SoftReference` caches by default and may includes a simple LRU cache.

The cache is pretty "lite" however, in keeping with ORMLite's name.  @Manmal is certainly right when he mentions the limitations of Hibernate's cache and how it can trick you if you are not careful.

I assume that this will be a work in progress and we may start an `ormlite-cache` package with some more complicated caches in the future.

Comment: Is it possible that ormlite does not go threw an entity to autorefresh collections when it is already stored in the cache?

somehow the cached entities contain forign fields which have not been initialized properly.